# Spring MVC Controller common logic

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying figure out best possible way to write a common logic in Spring MVC application. I have a Controller A which would be called which would invoke any another Controller based on request attributes which return [json](/questions/tagged/json) data.

I want the response back in controller A so that i can write common enrichment logic and send it back to browser. My intent is write enrichment logic only at one place and every request goes through it.

Answer (score 1):

What your are looking for are so called `HandlerInterceptor` or `ControllerAdvice`.

I made a small repository on Github about [Spring MVC Interception](https://github.com/aepfli/springMVCInterception) a while ago, it is a small Spring Boot application, which is showing you the ways to intercept a request with Spring MVC.

The question is always what is your main goal:

1. Do you want to just manipulate the output (e.g. adding a common field)? Use `ControllerAdvice`.
2. Do you want to call a logic before and after, without manipulating the request? Go for filters.
3. Do you want to change the object fundamentally (e.g. wrap it with another object)? Go for `HandlerInterceptor`.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can create abstract controller class and put the common logic or code in it. So wherever you want to use this common code just extend this class and use it.

For example :

```
public class AbstractController{
// common logic
}

public class A extends AbstractController{}

public class B extends AbstractController{}

public class C extends AbstractController{}
```